# LaTeX does not compile into pdf

Tags: latex

[TexMaker settings 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxFRJ.png)

[TexMaker settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8H0Cq.png)

I am new to LaTeX and it appears I cannot compile code (even the simplest) into a pdf view. When I use the quickbuild command it shows:

> Could not start the command. `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

I use "TexMaker", MikTeX console has all updates, LaTeX is recognized using Windows command console, the file is properly saved.

Simply restarting everything does not work.

(and that's all the code there is for the file)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

**Problem solved**

Thanks to samcarter, I added the path to pdflatex.exe in Options => Commands => PdfLaTeX to the command line and it works fine now.

Comment: Could you please upload the tex tile?

Comment: Can you show your texmaker settings?

Comment: As a test to find out where the problem is: Can you replace `pdflatex -synctex....` with the full path, e.g. `"C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/pdflatex" -synctex....` ? (check that pdflatex is indeed in this location)

Comment: @samcarter Just added the path to pdflatex.exe in the command line and it works fine. Thank you!